# Error received during the gnuplot draw

Tags: ubuntu, csv, utf-8, character-encoding, gnuplot

I try to draw a graphic using a csv with gnuplot. My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
set datafile separator ":"
set terminal pngcairo font ",8" size 1500,1000
set output '/path_to/mychart.png'
set style data histograms
set format y '%.0f'
set xtics right rotate by 45 font ',8'
set bmargin 10
set title "some graph title"
set xlabel "some x axis name"
set ylabel "some y axis name"
plot "/path_to/my.csv" using 2:xticlabels(1) notitle
```

During the script run-time, I receive an error message like:

Unable to convert "Some network parameter name                              �W-": the sequence is invalid in the current charset (UTF-8), falling back to iso_8859_1

Actually it is repeating same message for each parameter (which are actually xtics for the graph) in the csv file. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 on VirtualBox client on Windows 7 host.

The script is somehow drawing the graph, but strange characters appear on the x axis. Y axis (which consists of numbers) is fine. Graph itself is fine as well.

Is this a bug or some missing charset in OS?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post one of the relevant lines from your data file?

Comment: These are 3 lines from my file:

    Non IPv4 Discard Count                             : 311360
    IPv4 Fragmented Count                              : 224637512
    IPv4 Non Fragmented Count                          : 2608743892
IPv4 UDP Lower Count                               : 2607743957


And actually I found that if I modify xticks, and yticks font size, these strange characters on the x axis are also changing.

Comment: Just found it now. Top lines of my files consist of a header like:

---------------------------------------------------------------
----------------LAYER 3 STATISTICS----------------

Could this header cause the problem?

Comment: Nope. I removed the header, still same thing. After all I used : as a delimiter so it should ignore all other lines.